# Self-pointing foreign key query names not IDs

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

Lets say I have a table,

```
CREATE TABLE EntityType
(
    ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    Name varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    ParentTypeID int
)
ALTER TABLE EntityType ADD CONSTRAINT EntityType_ParentTypeID_FK FOREIGN KEY(ParentTypeID) REFERENCES EntityType(ID)
```

**How would I do a query such that I would replace ParentTypeIDs with the Name field that the ParentTypeIDs point to?**
I've tried,

```
SELECT [dbo].[EntityType].ID, [dbo].[EntityType].Name, [dbo].[EntityType].ParentTypeID
FROM [dbo].[EntityType]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[EntityType] ON [dbo].[EntityType].ParentTypeID = [dbo].[EntityType].Name
```

Obviously this is wrong, but I'm clueless on how to do a reference to a key that points to itself. Without the Join it works, but like I said I want to replace ParentTypeID with the appropriate names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select  et1.ID,
        et1.Name,
        et2.Name as ParentName
from    dbo.EntityType et1 join dbo.EntityType et2 on et1.ParentTypeID = et2.ID
```

Comment: Kind of hitting myself for this one. The second I seen your answer I was just like "but it was so obvious!!??" haha. Thanks, I don't know why I didn't think of giving an alias to the join table. I guess it was because of the mindset that it was the same table.

Comment: It is a best practice to always alias every table and every field reference. It makes the query more maintainable.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT e.ID, p.Name, e.ParentTypeID
FROM [dbo].[EntityType] e
INNER JOIN [dbo].[EntityType] p ON e.ParentTypeID = p.ID
```